# Spring Aware interfaces order

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, interface, inversion-of-control, lifecycle

Supossing a bean that implements all the Aware interfaces in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware.html

Do those interfaces get called always in a particular order in the life cycle?

The interfaces I'm talking about are: ApplicationContextAware, ApplicationEventPublisherAware, BeanClassLoaderAware, BeanFactoryAware, BeanNameAware, BootstrapContextAware, EmbeddedValueResolverAware, EnvironmentAware, ImportAware, LoadTimeWeaverAware, MessageSourceAware, NotificationPublisherAware, ResourceLoaderAware, SchedulerContextAware, ServletConfigAware and ServletContextAware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the docs for `BeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) and the [`ApplicationContextAwareProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java#L102):

> Bean factory implementations should support the standard bean
>   lifecycle interfaces as far as possible. The full set of
>   initialization methods and their standard order is:
>
> - `BeanNameAware's` `setBeanName`
> - `BeanClassLoaderAware`'s setBeanClassLoader
> - `BeanFactoryAware`'s `setBeanFactory`
> - `EnvironmentAware`'s setEnvironment
> - `EmbeddedValueResolverAware`'s setEmbeddedValueResolver
> - `ResourceLoaderAware`'s setResourceLoader (only applicable when running in an application context)
> - `ApplicationEventPublisherAware`'s `setApplicationEventPublisher` (only applicable when running in an application context)
> - `MessageSourceAware`'s `setMessageSource` (only    applicable when running in an application context)
> - `ApplicationContextAware`'s `setApplicationContext` (only applicable when    running in an application context)
> - `ServletContextAware`'s    `setServletContext` (only applicable when running in a web application    context)
> - `postProcessBeforeInitialization` methods of    `BeanPostProcessor`s
> - `InitializingBean`'s afterPropertiesSet
> - a custom    `init`-method definition
> - `postProcessAfterInitialization` methods of `BeanPostProcessors`

You'll notice that's not the full list. Some (i.e. `ImportAware`) get [dynamically added to the list of `PostProcessor`s](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java#L254) based on how their parent Configuration contexts are imported. That being the case, you can assume they are at the end of the list, and if you need more specifics, you can trace those in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you so much Dovmo. That's exactly what I was looking for.